# export grass-gis pansharpened image

Tags: grass-gis, export, pansharpening, grass-7.2

I have pansharpened my spot 6 image within grass 72 using `i.fusion.hpf` and it work well!

```
i.fusion.hpf pan=SPOT6_P_20151113@PERMANENT msx=SPOT6_MS_20151113.1@PERMANENT,SPOT6_MS_20151113.2@PERMANENT,SPOT6_MS_20151113.3@PERMANENT,SPOT6_MS_20151113.4@PERMANENT suffix=_hpf
i.colors.enhance red=SPOT6_MS_20151113.1._hpf@PERMANENT green=SPOT6_MS_20151113.2._hpf@PERMANENT blue=SPOT6_MS_20151113.3._hpf@PERMANENT
```

[image: grass i.fusion.hpf]

Now I would like to export this work in a multi-band raster. For that I have made a group.

```
i.group group=SPOT6_MS_20151113_hpf input=SPOT6_MS_20151113.1._hpf@PERMANENT,SPOT6_MS_20151113.2._hpf@PERMANENT,SPOT6_MS_20151113.3._hpf@PERMANENT,SPOT6_MS_20151113.4._hpf@PERMANENT
```

And tried to export this group... by when I open the exported file in Qgis ...

```
 r.out.gdal --overwrite input=SPOT6_MS_20151113_hpf output="/home/delaye/Documents/futurSahel/IMAGERIE SAT/pansharp/SPOT6_MS_20151113_hpf.tiff" format=GTiff type=Float64
```

the resolution is not what I'm waiting for

[image: in qgis]

I missed something, but where ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be sure to set the computational region right prior to the export, see https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region

In your case:

```
g.region raster=SPOT6_MS_20151113.1._hpf@PERMANENT
# i.group already done...
r.out.gdal --overwrite input=SPOT6_MS_20151113_hpf output="/home/delaye/Documents/futurSahel/IMAGERIE SAT/pansharp/SPOT6_MS_20151113_hpf.tiff" format=GTiff type=Float64
```

BTW: I would not use Float64, likely Float32 is precise enought here.